# Troubleshoot High CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu, high-cpu-usage

my pc got some issues after a update b360-9400F to b460-10400
My CPU usage is always at 10-15%. I have reinstall some different Windows version with drivers updated, replace other chipset but not work. So I used WPT to check  and you can see this image below:

[highCPUUsage_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SSj2.png)

File highCPUUsage.etl if need :https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiuMUhwmWfX_kWcgw2mwDTLnzu29?e=QIxqlA

My PC parameters:

- Windows 10 PRO
- B460F
- Intel Core i5 10400
- 16 GB RAM
- NVIDIA RTX 3060ti
- SSD SamSung EVO 970(boot) + SSD Crucial P1 + HHD WDBlue

I'd appreciate any help attempt! Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For bloated ntoskrnl.exe (high CPU usage and or high memory usage):

Go here :[Link blog.pcrisk.com how to fix it](https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12536-ntoskrnlexe-process-is-causing-high-cpu-or-disk-usage-how-to-fix-it)

And there is a youtube video too if you didn't want to the unfamiliar website : [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09Z693m4bZM)

But for quick reference, this is because memory management in windows 10 is expanded in your Memory making it further to eat CPU resource to manage the big memory files to scan read, and write.

Like superfetch, runtime broker and pagefile is the main culprit.

Set your pagefile to fix size usually 0.5~1x of your memory size. Ex: your memory is 16GB, set your pagefile 8GB up to 16GB.

How to set the virtual memory/pagefile:
[image: How to set]

Comment: I tried before and it not work. Thank you!